# how to manually upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 so I can upgrade fully

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 15.04, documentation

Getting the error `an upgrade from vivid to xenial is not supported`.
I need to know how to manually upgrade from v 15.04 to 15.10 so I can then upgrade to 16.whatevs as per usual.

I have tried

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and used the software updater program, and both return the same error. I do not want to skip versions from 15.04 to 16.x, I just want to manually install 15.10 from my current version, and that should allow `do-release-upgrade` to fix the rest.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't want to skip releases, I just want to proceed up the ladder to the latest release and I can't.
Using software updater gives me the error mentioned in my original post, and I can't see any other method of installing upgrades.
I've tried sudo do-release-upgrade and get the same error.

Comment: was missing the -d. Finally got it working, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 8):

Set

`software & updates -> Updates -> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`

to

`For any new version`

and run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I thought `-d` was for servers only, but evidently not.

Comment: -d is for development releases.